# Requests download with retries creates large corrupt zip

Tags: python, python-requests

relative beginner here. I'm trying to complete a basic task with Requests, downloading zip files. It works fine on most downloads, but intermittently writes over-sized, corrupt zip files when working with large downloads (>5 GB or so). For example, there is a zip file I know to be ~11 GB that shows up anywhere between 16 and 20 GB, corrupted.

When unzipping in Windows Explorer, I get "The compressed (zipped) folder is invalid". 7-Zip will extract the archive, but says:

Headers Error --- Unconfirmed start of archive --- Warnings: There are some data after the end of the payload data

Interestingly, the 7-Zip dialog shows the correct file size as 11479 MB.

Here's my code:

```
save_dir = Path(f"{dirName}/{item_type}/{item_title}.zip")
file_to_resume = save_dir
try:
    with requests.get(url, stream=True, timeout=30) as g:
        with open(save_dir, 'wb') as sav:
            for chunk in g.iter_content(chunk_size=1024*1024):
                sav.write(chunk)
except:
    attempts = 0
    while attempts < 10:
        try:
            resume_header = {'Range':f'bytes = {Path(file_to_resume).stat().st_size}-'}
            with requests.get(url, stream=True, headers=resume_header, timeout=30) as f:                        
                with open(file_to_resume, 'ab') as sav:
                    for chunk in f.iter_content(chunk_size=1024*1024):
                        sav.write(chunk)
            break
        except:
            attempts += 1
```

Comment: Does the server support the `Range` header?

Comment: @RonieMartinez Thanks for pointing me to that. It appears it doesn't; I tried a request in curl with a range and got a 200 back, so it looks like it ignored the range.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the server did not support the Range header. Thanks, @RonieMartinez.